# How can I make images globally accessible to other classes?

Tags: java, image, ioexception

I have several images like the one used below in my program. I decided to move all my images to a separate image class to keep my program tidy, but now I am encountering *unhandled* `IOException` errors.

By coding `Images.fileName` I am able to reference the `File`, but it requires that file to be `static`, and when I change it to `static`, I encounter an `IOException`.

```
final BufferedImage identity = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Identity.jpg"));
```

I have dozens of `String` variables that can be accessed from other classes very easily. No problems at all, I don't even have to preface it with a `className.varName`.

Is there a way to fix this? or preferably a better way to do it?

Comment: could you please post your stacktrace regarding IOException?

Comment: edit your question and append your stacktrace there

Comment: The class with the images isn't meant to be run. It exists only to hold my images. Unless I am misunderstanding, I thought the stack trace was the red error text you get when there is a runtime problem?

Comment: You're dealing with the problem in the wrong way. Your problem has nothing to do with images. Your problem is that you don't understand a compiler error message related to unhandled exceptions. So read the error message, try to make sense of it, google it, read a tutorial about exceptions in Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), and fix your code. And, if you're really stuck, then post the code that doesn't compile along with the complete and exact error message. But the tutorial should allow you to understand why your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

What [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) said in their comment is fully correct:

> You're dealing with the problem in the wrong way. Your problem has
>   nothing to do with images. Your problem is that you don't understand a
>   compiler error message related to unhandled exceptions. So read the
>   error message, try to make sense of it, google it, read a tutorial
>   about exceptions in Java
>   ([docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)), and fix your
>   code. And, if you're really stuck, then post the code that doesn't
>   compile along with the complete and exact error message. But the
>   tutorial should allow you to understand why your code doesn't compile

Your problem lies within the fact that you're eagerly initializing your field without catching the IOException that may result. The fix for this problem is rather simple: Use a static initializer block:

```
public class MyImages {
    public static final BufferedImage identity;

    static {
       try {
           identity = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Identity.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // couldn't read the image...
           // do something about it or stop the program or whatever
       }
    }
    // the other stuff of your class
}
```